# DLL can't be accessed on some systems

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Our C# / .NET  program is calling a third party DLL (x.dll) in the target folder. x.dll is then calling another third party DLL y.dll in the same folder. At some systems, this does not work, because x.dll can't find y.dll.
The same program with the same dlls works on most other systems, but we can't find out what the differences are to the systems were it does not work. We checked the properties, the dlls are not blocked by Windows. Also the virus-scanner was disabled.

Comment: what about the .net versions? x86 and x64 differences?

Comment: Use ProcessMonitor and compare the traces from the two system and see where they differ and why

Answer (score 1):

Please go through [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) and see which case it applies. the most likely case is standard DLL search order with SafeDllSearchMode enabled:

> If SafeDllSearchMode is enabled, the search order is as follows:
>
> - The directory from which the application loaded.
> - The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> - The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
> - The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> - The current directory.
> - The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by
>     the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when
>     computing the DLL search path.

Note that if the DLL is a managed assembly (you do not mention it is) then the .Net assembly search rules apply, see [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies). Obviously, [GAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac) would also play a role for managed DLLs.

I'm just giving you the pointers to do your own investigations, since your post is missing the relevant info.